# IPad, how to change wallpaper for a lot of ipads connected to my mac

Tags: ipad, configuration, automation, wallpaper

i have 200 iPads and i have to change the wallpaper, setting the same on each ipad. I try to do this using apple configurator, but it don't allow me to set the backgroud image.
There is a way to do it without set wallpaper by hands for every ipad?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i use a notesynk able to connect 16 ipad for every usb port on my mac. Then i do a backup of one device with my wallpaper setted, then i do a restore using apple configurator and just works! ;)